# Google Formula: how to get immediately the first item of a split? Get first result when a formula returns multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets

The formula `SPLIT(CELL,DELIMITER)` fills multiple cells, but i want only for example the first result. How to do this?
In general: when a Google formula returns multiple answers (normally in a represented in a range), how do you only return one value in that range?

UPDATE: I found out the specific case aboven is also possible to solve it with regular expressions for everyone interested:

I found another solution by using regular expression. In this case I want everything up to the `(` symbol: `=REGEXEXTRACT(CELL;"(.+?) \(")` it matches the part between `(.+?)` and the `.` means everything, the `+` means at least one character and the `?` means nongreedy, so it will stop when encountering the rest of the expression (which is the `(` symbol). Also to avoid the `#N/A` error when there is no ( symbol, you write: `IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(C116;"(.+?) \(");C116)`

Comment: I found another solution by using regular expression. In this case I want everything up to the ( symbol: =REGEXEXTRACT(CELL;"(.+?) \(") it matches the part between (.+?) and the dot means everything, the + means at least one character and the ? means nongreedy, so it will stop when encountering the rest of the expression (which is the ( symbol)

Comment: If you have solved your own issue, please post your comment above as an answer post and then mark that post as "Best Answer." This will effectively "close" the post, signifying that it has been fully resolved.

Comment: I solved it, but my question/specific strategy is still open :) I'm curious so I'll update the question: how in general use one value when many values are returned by a google formula

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand your post or your goal. It might be easier if you *show* it via some examples on a sample spreadsheet and share the link here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your goal. But suppose you had the following string in cell A1:

`A,B,C,D,E`

You could obtain `A` with this formula:

`=INDEX(SPLIT(A1,","),1,1)`

If you wanted to have an array formula process similar strings in the entire column A:A, you would use this in, say, B1 (with the rest of B:B empty):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(A:A,","),ROWS(A:A),1)))`

Comment: Nice that solved it `=INDEX(SPLIT(A1,","),1,1)`

Comment: Great. Thanks for reporting back and for closing the post correctly by marking the answer as "Best Answer."

Comment: Thank you!! ARRAY_CONSTRAIN really helped me here 

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=SPLIT(A1, ",")&""
```

[image]